# Single service using thousands of threads

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, threads, performance-monitor

I have an windows application that is having performance and stability issues that our company has bought from a vendor.

**I noticed the application was using 1,000 - 4,000 threads**.  Could this be causing the stability and performance problems?  The cpu is not too high (50% of 16 cpus) and disk I/O is 7-20 Mb/sec which doesn't seem high either.

I would think the computer would be spending all it's time doing context switches with so many threads!

Any thoughts?

Comment: How exactly did you determine its opening that many threads, which doesn't tell you very much, if the CPU usage is only at 50%.  In other words **doubtful** I have seen applications have more threads by 3x to 4x that.

Comment: I saw in the windows performance monitor, it was opening 4-6 every second.

Comment: The number of threads was increasing by 4-6 per second? Continuously? Also: Do you really have 16 CPU cores, or is this with hyperthreading enabled?

Comment: It was using 4-6 more threads with each second.  I believe that is without hyperthreading, since I believe windows performance monitor shows 1 graph per cpu..

Comment: Actually I have 2 cores/4 logical cores.  It looks like windows performance monitor does show logical cores.